# Cannot un -sync sms sync on galaxy s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have just restored my galaxy s4 as i was having trouble with it. now, all my texts are going to my email. i have gone to the option ünsync sms"but it wont work! it just says unable to change sms settings at this time. What do i do?

Comment: Where can I find Unsync SMS? I also have an S4, but don't know where that is. Maybe I can help.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the account and set it up again , before finishing unsync sms...